# socket.io reconnecting when connecting remotely

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reconnect

I copied and deployed the socket.io's demo code (found at http://socket.io/ on the front page).
I have a server.js and a index.html with this demo code

When I run 'node server.js' locally, and then open index.html locally, everything works fine and I connect to the server.
The server outputs:

```
info - handshake authorized XXXXXXXXX
```

However, when I put the server.js on a remote server, but open index.html locally, It keeps reconnecting.
The server outputs:

```
info - handshake authorized XXXXXXXXX
info - handshake authorized XXXXXXXXX
info - handshake authorized XXXXXXXXX
info - handshake authorized XXXXXXXXX
```

and so on.

I've had a hard time finding any info on this.
How am I supposed to build an application that initializes when a client connects, if it's being constantly reconnected?

This same reconnect pattern occurs when I run server.js locally, and connect to it from a remote server.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated the url of the socket you want to connect to on the client-side?

var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com:port');